# passing parameter to replace a keyword

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

I have many links on one page of a sharepoint. My requirement is to pass a parameter with the link and change certain keys of another page how do i do this ?

Comment: You add the link with CSR/JSlink script( Client Side Rendering) to the HREF data attribute of the A tag you create; on the other page you then read ``document.location.href`` and parse your QueryString parameter from it. You then have the values to change the keys on the other page using ``document.querySelector``

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to fetch query string parameters:

Assuming that the page url is somewhat as below:

```
https://sitecollectionurl/pages/test.aspx?technology=jquery
```

1) Using the javascript method:

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) {
      url = window.location.href;
    }
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

Usage:

```
var tech = getParameterByName('technology')
```

2) Using the OOTB SharePoint methods

```
var tech = GetUrlKeyValue("technology");
```

or

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup(); 
var tech = JSRequest.QueryString["technology"]
```

Now, that you have got the query string value, you will have to iterate it over your keys.

Assuming that the keys are anchor and have the class name as link -

```
//using jquery
//assuming that they are anchors having class name as link
$('.link a').each(function(){
    this.href = this.href.replace("https://yahoo.com", "http://google.com?technology"+tech);
});
```

or Using vanila js:

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.link a'), function(a){
    a.href = a.href.replace("https://yahoo.com", "http://google.com?technology"+tech);
});
```

over Simplified

```
var anchors = document.querySelectorAll(".link a");
for (var j = 0; j < anchors.length; ++j) {
    var anchor = anchors[j];
    anchor.href = anchor.href.replace("https://yahoo.com", "http://google.com?technology"+tech);
}
```

[Replace multiple links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39735452/replace-multiple-links)

[Some useful Javascript variables/functions in Sharepoint](https://praneethmoka.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/some-useful-javascript-variablesfunctions-in-sharepoint/)

[get query string values in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks Gautham for the detailed replay. I have a URL say https://sitecollectionurl/pages/test.aspx?name=Rinu .  and i tried edit Source of the page and add this code <script>  GetUrlKeyValue('MyVar', window.location.href); </script> but as soon as i save, the script tag goes disappears. will script work with the HTML of the page or should it only works with script editor ? Sorry i am pretty new to this

Comment: you should create a js file and store it inside site assets/style library. Then in the script editor add reference as `<script src="https://path-to-sitecollection/siteassets/test.js"></script>` where test.js contains your logic. After that save the webpart and then page and then debug. Also, based on comments, it should be `GetUrlKeyValue('name', window.location.href); ` , store it in a js variable and then use it to replace the anchor or whatever your keys are.

Comment: How do i get reference to the body of the sharepoint page? i found the code function replaceText() {
    var orignalstring = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    var ReplaceStr = GetUrlKeyValue('name', window.location.href);
    var newstring = orignalstring.replace("txt1", "ReplaceStr");
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = newstring;
}  But not sure how to get the body of the sharepoint page

Comment: to get the body you can use `document.body` in javascript and in jquery you can use it as `$(document.body)` or `$('body')`

Comment: Here is my .js file     function replaceText() {
    var orignalstring = document.body.innerHTML.toString();
    var ReplaceStr = GetUrlKeyValue('name', window.location.href);
    var newstring = orignalstring.replace("txt1", "ReplaceStr");
    document.body.innerHTML = newstring;
}

Comment: i have added the above function in a js file and referred it as below in a script editor  <script src="https://mysite-collection-path to the .jsfile/siteassets/myjsfile.js"></sc‌​ript> <script type="text/javascript">replaceText() ;</sc‌​ript> But it seems to be not working